# Why does Tomcat try to use the cache when compilation failed?

Tags: tomcat, java, cache, jsp

For some reason, it appears Tomcat is trying to hit its compilation cache when compilation failed.

For example, if I create a JSP containing nothing but `Hello, <%=world%>!`, predictably, I get an error: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP`. Subsequent requests however alternate between this and `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP`.

Further, if I create a JSP containing `Hello!`, it of course works just fine. If I modify it contain `Hello, <%=name%>!`, the response alternates between the previously-mentioned compilation error, and the cached `Hello!`.

What's going on?

Comment: Doesn't this belong on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Apparently, JSPs are checked every `interval` for changes for performance reasons. It is possible to configure Tomcat to check on every request instead.

In `web.xml`, look for:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
```

and add:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>development</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>modificationTestInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Credit to [albert's blog](http://albert-myptc.blogspot.com/2006/05/tomcat-disable-tomcat-cache.html) for pointing me in the right direction.

EDIT: I also found [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48795), which seems to suggest that some buggy behaviour on the part of Tomcat is involved.